# How to exclude _id without including other fields using the aggregation framework

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I would like to get the result of an aggregation pipeline without the _id filed. I know this is possible if you provide explicitly other fields that will be the output of the projection. But, ¿how can I mimic the $projec in a find call?

This is what I want (**No field explicitly included**):

```
db.col.find({},{_id:0})
```

But in the aggregation framework seems to be impossible:

```
db.col.aggregate([{'$project': {_id:0}}])

Error: Printing Stack Trace
    at printStackTrace (src/mongo/shell/utils.js:37:15)
    at DBCollection.aggregate (src/mongo/shell/collection.js:927:9)
    at (shell):1:11
2013-10-07T16:36:09.273+0200 aggregate failed: {
    "errmsg" : "exception: $projection requires at least one output field",
    "code" : 16403,
    "ok" : 0
} at src/mongo/shell/collection.js:928
```

Any idea to workaround this issue ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When using aggregation, you must explicitly [include/exclude fields](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project). So, you'd need to list all the fields you want. It's not equivalent to `find`. So, you might:

```
db.sample.aggregate(
    { $project : {
        _id : 0,
        title : 1             
    }}
);
```

Using the aggregation framework also comes with some [limits](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/#pipeline) you should be aware of. It's designed for aggregation (grouping, summing, etc.), so having many fields in a projection isn't as typical (and could cause results to exceed the maximum allowed, which is 16MB).

Comment: Mongodb 2.6 will overcome these limits... "By returning a cursor, aggregation pipelines can return result sets of any size" http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.6/

I am trying 2.5.2 but stills need to explicitly include fields. It's a pity. :(

Comment: Sure, a future version may remove these limits. But, for now, this is what it is. The Aggregation Framework is still best for grouping, etc, and in those cases, returning many fields usually doesn't make sense.

Comment: you are awesome ! Finally I solved the problem! plus one from me